# Leaded wave soldering temperature on "lead free PCB"

Tags: pcb, soldering, manufacturing

I've a question regarding what temperature is recommended on a leaded wave soldering machine?

**Background of question**

The case is that I've the option to use a leaded (when customer allows) or a lead-free soldering machine. I've tested the lead-free with the problematic result that the solder won't float up, where the production was unable to improve the soldering afterwards. So I've tested the leaded wave soldering, with much better result. However my gut feeling says me that the temperature that was used in this leaded machine, is to high >400Celsius, because the lead-free use a temperature of <400Celsius. So that is the origin of my question.

The PCB is of 6 layers with a lot of copper and heatsinks, with lead-free plating.

I hope someone could help or come with some kind of recommendation.

Best regards

Comment: What *is* the plating? HASL? ENIG? Other?

Comment: Seems to be;
"Surface treatment : Selective tin leadfree Sn100C"

Comment: @AntonIngemarson - "leaded machine [...] >400Celsius" "lead-free [...] <400Celsius" Are you sure those temperatures are the correct way around? They look reversed to me, since lead-free solder melts at a *higher* temperature than leaded (typically).

Comment: Yes it's true, it's why I got a bad feeling.